# R read comma delimited txt file with comma inside one column

Tags: r, url, csv

I have the logs of some users' browsing behavior. It's from the data collector and apparently he used commas to separate variables. However some URLs do have commas inside. I can't read the txt file into R.

```
20091,2009-06-02 22:06:14,84,taobao.com,search1.taobao.com,http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1,www.taobao.com,shopping,e-commerce,C2C
20092,2009-06-16 12:25:35,8,sohu.com,www.wap.sohu.com,http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387,www.sohu.com,portal,entertainment,mobile
20092,2009-06-07 16:02:03,14,eetchina.com,www.powersystems.eetchina.com,http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT,,others,marketing,enterprise
20096,2009-06-30 07:51:38,7,taobao.com,search1.taobao.com,http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-1----------------------0----------------------g,zhh3viy-g,ywtmf7glxeqnhjgt263ps-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?ssid=p1-s1,search1.taobao.com,shopping,e-commerce,C2C
2009184,2009-06-25 14:40:39,6,mktginc.com,surv.mktginc.com,,,unknown,unknown,unknown
20092,2009-06-07 15:13:06,32,ccb.com.cn,ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn,https://ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn/app/V5/CN/STY1/login.jsp,,e-bank,finance,e-bank
```

The URLs above should be:

```
http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1
http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387
http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT
http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-1----------------------0----------------------g,zhh3viy-g,ywtmf7glxeqnhjgt263ps-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?ssid=p1-s1

https://ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn/app/V5/CN/STY1/login.jsp
```

How can I tell R there are exactly 10 variables in each line and put commas in URL there? Thanks!

```
df <- read.table('2009.txt', sep= ',', quote= '', comment.char= '', stringsAsFactors= F)
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : line 130 did not have 10 elements
```

Comment: I assume you can't fix this at the source (having it provide valid CSV data)?

Comment: Also, could there be more than one instance of a field that starts with `http` per line?

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker! No...I can't change the source. Otherwise I'll ask him to use tab instead of asking on SO. I got the file from a secondhand of a secondhand...very complicated. There's only one URL column and I don't think there would be two `http`s here. Unless someone visited `ftp://nas.myserv.ip`... I haven't met one yet.

Comment: The last line has 14 columns.  I'm almost there but what is supposed to be in the last line?

Comment: @RichardScriven no, the URL is `http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT`, the commas are inside the URL

Comment: @leoce What about the 2nd and 1st line? Is it a single `url`?  In the first line after `taobao.com`, there is a `,`.  I am guessing that is a real delimiter.

Comment: @akrun I've updated the question with three more lines about the URL, thanks!

Comment: @leoce It is better to show an example that mimics your original dataset.

Comment: @leoce Thanks for the update.  Yes, my regexpr won't fit because it was based on `lookahead` with `www` or `,,` in your previous example.  If there is a regular pattern as to where your url's end, for example the possible number of starting points after the `,`, we can work something out.  Otherwise, it is non-specific.

Comment: @leoce I updated again with your `https` dataset

Comment: @leoce I think there is some misunderstanding.  You can post that as a separate solution.  I will edit the part just got updated by iTech

Comment: @akrun I thought about posting my own solution. Then I might just accept my answer. I'd like to give Josh the credit... and I don't want people to miss my updated solution either, if they check the question in the future and only read the accepted answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read in the data such that each line is a single string (e.g. `sep="\n"`), then you can process each line directly before putting into a proper data frame.

If only the 6th entry could potentially have commas (it looks like the other urls are only the main domains), then something like the following could work:

```
d <- strsplit(d, ",")

for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  x <- d[[i]]
  n <- length(x)
  if (n > 10) {
    d[[i]] <- c(x[1:5], paste(x[6:(n-4)], collapse=","), x[(n-3):n])
  }
}

d <- do.call(rbind,lapply(d, matrix, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE))
```

If other urls could have the issue, this approach might still work, but it could get very complicated.

Comment: Please add my update if you consider it a complementary script. Thanks, @Josh! `http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5892285`

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
  dat <- read.table(text=gsub("http:.*(?=(,www)|,,)(*SKIP)(*F)|,", "*",
           Lines, perl=TRUE), sep="*", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  dat
  #    V1                  V2 V3           V4                            V5
  #1 20091 2009-06-02 22:06:14 84   taobao.com            search1.taobao.com
  #2 20092 2009-06-16 12:25:35  8     sohu.com              www.wap.sohu.com
  #3 20092 2009-06-07 16:02:03 14 eetchina.com www.powersystems.eetchina.com
   #                     V6
  #1               http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq------- 2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1
  #2       http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387
  #3 http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT
  #            V7       V8            V9        V10
  #1 www.taobao.com shopping    e-commerce        C2C
  #2   www.sohu.com   portal entertainment     mobile
  #3                  others     marketing enterprise
```

#### data

```
 Lines <-  readLines(textConnection(txt)) #(`txt` from @Richard Scriven)
```

#### Update

Using your new dataset

```
 indx <- grep("http", Lines)
 Lines1 <- Lines[indx]
 pat1 <- paste(unique(gsub(".*http[s]?.{3}(\\w+)\\..*", "\\1", Lines1)), collapse="|")
 pat1N <-  paste0("http:.*(?=,(", pat1, "|,))(*SKIP)(*F)|,") 

 dat1 <-  read.table(text=gsub(pat1N, "*", Lines, perl=TRUE),
                   sep="*", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 dat1
 #           V1                  V2 V3           V4                            V5
 #1   20091 2009-06-02 22:06:14 84   taobao.com            search1.taobao.com
 #2   20092 2009-06-16 12:25:35  8     sohu.com              www.wap.sohu.com
 #3   20092 2009-06-07 16:02:03 14 eetchina.com www.powersystems.eetchina.com
 #4   20096 2009-06-30 07:51:38  7   taobao.com            search1.taobao.com
 #5 2009184 2009-06-25 14:40:39  6  mktginc.com              surv.mktginc.com
 #6   20092 2009-06-07 15:13:06 32   ccb.com.cn          ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn
 #                                     V6
 # 1                                            http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1
 # 2                                    http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387
 # 3                              http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT
 # 4 http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-1----------------------0----------------------g,zhh3viy-g,ywtmf7glxeqnhjgt263ps-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?ssid=p1-s1
 #5                                                                                                                                                                         
 #6                                                                                                                       https://ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn/app/V5/CN/STY1/login.jsp
#                 V7       V8            V9        V10
#1     www.taobao.com shopping    e-commerce        C2C
#2       www.sohu.com   portal entertainment     mobile
#3                      others     marketing enterprise
#4 search1.taobao.com shopping    e-commerce        C2C
#5                     unknown       unknown    unknown
#6                      e-bank       finance     e-bank
```

#### data

```
 txt <- '20091,2009-06-02 22:06:14,84,taobao.com,search1.taobao.com,http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1,www.taobao.com,shopping,e-commerce,C2C
20092,2009-06-16 12:25:35,8,sohu.com,www.wap.sohu.com,http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387,www.sohu.com,portal,entertainment,mobile
20092,2009-06-07 16:02:03,14,eetchina.com,www.powersystems.eetchina.com,http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT,,others,marketing,enterprise
20096,2009-06-30 07:51:38,7,taobao.com,search1.taobao.com,http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-1----------------------0----------------------g,zhh3viy-g,ywtmf7glxeqnhjgt263ps-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?ssid=p1-s1,search1.taobao.com,shopping,e-commerce,C2C
2009184,2009-06-25 14:40:39,6,mktginc.com,surv.mktginc.com,,,unknown,unknown,unknown
20092,2009-06-07 15:13:06,32,ccb.com.cn,ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn,https://ibsbjstar.ccb.com.cn/app/V5/CN/STY1/login.jsp,,e-bank,finance,e-bank'

  Lines <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
```

Comment: I must say, that is impressive

Comment: @RichardScriven @akrun Thanks to both! I get the idea of both your scripts. The environment of production is messed up. The data have empty URL cells also, like `2009184,2009-06-25 14:40:39,6,mktginc.com,surv.mktginc.com,,,unknown,unknown,unknown`. Therefore both your scripts would throw an error. akrun's would say 'line 309 did not have 10 elements' while Richard's is due to g=0 'Error in g:(length(x) - 4) : argument of length 0'. I might try the if flow by Josh

Comment: @leoce My script was based on the example you provided.  It is better to show an example that mimics the original dataset.  If you have those without URL cells, I would suggest you to `grep` those lines out and use the script on the others.  Later join them together using indexing.

Comment: @akrun thanks! I've updated my question. It seems that your regexpr pattern doesn't fit in line 4 in my question (line 2138 in the file). Is is because there're too many dashes? And one more thing is that I suggest to put comment.char = '' in the function because there're # in the URLs.

Comment: @akrun Millions of thanks for your efforts! I just tried your script in the test. Then I found out it can't handle `https`...(updated in the question too). Maybe it's not a good idea to use regexpr, 'cause we can't exhaust all the possibilities...unless I can read through 115,280 lines.

Comment: @leoce perhaps try `pat1 <- paste(unique(gsub(".*http(s)?.{3}(\\w+)\\..*", "\\1", Lines1)), collapse="|")` Not tested though.

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the patch. However it leaves `pat1N <-  paste0("http:.*(?=,(", pat1, "|,))(*SKIP)(*F)|,")` unchanged... I modified and tested Josh's approach and I have to say it's pretty fast `http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5892285`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62195/discussion-between-leoce-and-akrun).

Comment: @iTech  I guess you should post it as a separate answer ?

Comment: Hmm...why is @iTech copying my solution added in Josh's answer? `http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5892285`

Comment: @leoce I have no idea.  I just found my post got edited now :-)

Comment: Looks like someone didn't get lots of hard earned credits! Thanks again, @akrun !

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might work for you.

```
txt <- '20091,2009-06-02 22:06:14,84,taobao.com,search1.taobao.com,http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1,www.taobao.com,shopping,e-commerce,C2C
  20092,2009-06-16 12:25:35,8,sohu.com,www.wap.sohu.com,http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387,www.sohu.com,portal,entertainment,mobile
  20092,2009-06-07 16:02:03,14,eetchina.com,www.powersystems.eetchina.com,http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT,,others,marketing,enterprise'

readLog <-  function(file, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
{
    s <- strsplit(readLines(file), ",")
    loop <- t(sapply(s, function(x) {
            g <- grep("http", x)
            x[g] <- paste(x[g:(length(x)-4)], collapse = ",")
            x[-c((g+1):(length(x)-4))]
        }))
    data.frame(loop, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
}
## readLog(textConnection(txt))
readLog(yourFile)
```

This gives the following in the 6th column, and each row has 10 columns

```
                                                                        V6
1               http://search1.taobao.com/browse/0/n-g,grdsa2kqn5scattbnzxq-------2-------b--40--commend-0-all-0.htm?at_topsearch=1&ssid=e-s1
2       http://www.wap.sohu.com/info/index.html?url=http://wap.sohu.com/sports/pic/?lpn=1&resIdx=0&nid=336&rid=KL39,PD21746&v=2&ref=901981387
3 http://www.powersystems.eetchina.com/ART_8800533274_2600005_TA_346f6b13.HTM?click_from=8800024853,8875136323,2009-05-26,PSCOL,ARTICLE_ALERT
```

And 7 through 10 are

```
              V7       V8            V9        V10
1 www.taobao.com shopping    e-commerce        C2C
2   www.sohu.com   portal entertainment     mobile
3                  others     marketing enterprise
```